# Передача файлов WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Создал сервис

```
namespace FileExchangeService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        FileMes GetFile(FileMes mes);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FileMes
    {
        [DataMember]
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        private byte[] _data;
        public byte[] Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

создал для него клиент со следующим методом передачи файла

```
        Stream strm = null;
        try
        {   
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }

            strm = fileDialog.OpenFile();
            if (strm != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)strm.Length];

                int i = strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    FileExchangeService.Service1 client = new Service1();
                    FileExchangeService.FileMes file = new FileMes();
                    file.Name = fileDialog.SafeFileName;
                    file.Data = buffer;
                    client.GetFile(file);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (strm != null)
            {
                strm.Close();
            }
        }
```

Теперь осталось задать удаленное место назначение файла и на удаленном устройстве принять этот файл. И тут ступор как это сделать не знаю и найти никакого толкового описания не получается. Нужно создать еще 1 приложение сервера, которому будет передаваться инфо о передаче файла и оно же будет отправлять его на 2е устройство(или его в данном случае заменяет сервис?) или что?

Для большей ясности.
Имеется локальная сеть из 2х компьютеров, требуется организовать между ними передачу файлов (средний размер 15-30 МБ) пока что ip адреса их известны на стадии написания кода, позже они будут известны только на стадии выполнения. В том ли я направлении двигаюсь? Есть ли хорошие статьи на эту тему? В гугле ничего толкового не нашел

Comment: А что уже есть? Вы можете установить клиентское соединение?

Comment: Со службой? Да вроде,пробовал открыть файл, передать его службе, забрать из нее и сохранить, вроде норм проходит

Comment: Подождите-подождите. А кто устанавливает. куда именно должен записаться файл — сервер или клиент? // По идее, вы всё делаете правильно, не вижу особенных проблем в вашем подходе.

Comment: Не имеет значения кто будет решать куда записывать,  но по идее правильней делать это принимающей стороне, обмен нужен в оба конца, но один компьютер инициализирует отправку на второй и он же запрашивает у второго файлы. Пути сохранения известны на стадии разработки

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно, где осталась проблема. (1) Клиент инициирует соединение с сервером. (2) Клиент запрашивает у пользователя путь для сохранения. (3) Клиент запрашивает у сервера файл, получает его содержимое в ответе. (4) Клиент записывает файл по пути из п (2).

Comment: Проблема в том что не могу понять как установить связь между сервером и клиентом, где и какими методами задавать адрес клиента и сервера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам нужно WCF service discovery.

Официальный пример Microsoft лежит [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456783%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), полная информация [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Краткая выжимка: В хост вашего сервера нужно добавить

```
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
serviceHost.Description.Endpoints.Add(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

а в клиент вот что:

```
var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
Collection<EndpointDiscoveryMetadata> services = 
        discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IYourServiceInterface))).Endpoints;

discoveryClient.Close();

if (services.Count == 0)
{
    // не найдено
}
else
{
    var client = new YourClient();
    // берём первый, например
    client.Endpoint.Address = services[0].EndpointAddress;
    // пользуемся клиентом тут
}
```

Comment: `Collection<EndpointDiscoveryMetadata> services = 
        discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IYourServiceInterface)));`   выдает ошибку приведения типа

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Угу, забыл добавить `Endpoints`. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: Добавил вместо `YourClient()` `Client1Service`  и вместо `calculatorServices[0].EndpointAddress` `new EndpointAddrees(new Uri("localhost")` больше ни на что не ругается вроде но как теперь проверить связь?

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Ой, снова моя ошибка, вам нужно `services[0].EndpointAddress`. Исправил. Попробуйте запустить на двух машинах в одной подсети запустить сервер и клиент, и посмотрите, увидит ли клиент endpoint сервера.

Comment: запустил пока клиент и сервер на одной машине, `services.Count==0`

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Хм. Маловато как-то. А если убрать условие в `Find`, что-то находится?

Comment: также 0, попытался добавить контрольное значение для `discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria())` долго думал и выдал время ожидания истекло

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32156/discussion-between-artemiy-borodin-and-vladd).

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: А сервер у вас запущен?

Comment: Да запущен,если его не запустить то выдает эксепшн

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Странно, у меня работает на одном хосте, только что перепроверил. А может, вы запретили announcement фаерволом случайно?

Comment: Специально не запрещал вроде, мб система автоматом запрещает

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Гляньте в свойства firewall'а. Может, сервер не может открыть порт — попробуйте запустить его с правами администратора.

Comment: поковырялся еще, с горем пополам сделал трансфер файлов(пока небольших) ответ помог)

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Отлично! А как обошли проблему с видимостью?

Comment: много раз переделывал все, в итоге получилось добавив тип при инициализации хоста, изменив `EndpointAddress` на `http://localhost:8001` и запустив сервер от имени администратора(иначе выдает `AddressAccessDeniedException`, пока другой адрес стоял ошибок не выдавал, но и не работал)

Comment: Сервер должен бежать от админа, да. А Discovery не сработало?