# Автоматическое переподключение к серверу wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

Как можно сделать автоматическое переподключение к серверу WCF с клиента, если соединение полностью потеряно. 
У меня каждую секунду на сервис приходит информация, это я сделал с помощью System.Timers. Когда сервер теряет связь с клиентом, выпадает Exception и я выключаю Timer, вызываю функцию, где заново регистрируется сервер, и включаю Timer. Это вполне работает, и когда я включаю сервер информация все равно идет, но также почему-то еще падают некоторое время Exception, и снова происходит перерегистрация. Вот какая еще проблема, выпадает сразу несколько Exception(**CommunicationObjectFaultedException, EndpointNotFoundException**)
Есть может какой-нибудь нормальный способ сделать автоматическое переподключение к серверу?

> Может делать какой-нибудь автоматический поиск включенных серверов?

Comment: А методы с WCF сервиса вы вызываете синхронно или асинхронно? Причиной выпадения нескольких эксепшнов, имхо, может быть асинхронный вызов методов.

Comment: Асинхронно. Как-нибудь ситуация исправить можно?

Comment: Можно, но не очень уж просто. Насколько я понимаю, то суть примерно такова - на endpoint со стороны службы вешается дополнительные обработчики событий подключения/отключения клиента. В этих обработчиках можно на сервере понять, отвалился клиент или нет, и принять решение, слать данные клиенту, например, или нет.
Со стороны клиента можно поменять логику обработки ошибок в связке с попыткой подключения к сервису, т.е. если словили ошибку, то не тут же бежать и подключаться, а сначала проверить - может быть, подключение вновь уже поднято.

Comment: А если я буду использовать DiscoviryClient через метод Find, запущенные службы. Например, если потерялась связь с одной из службы, он в отдельном потоке будет запускать поиск этого Сервиса, и когда он найдет, подача данных возобновится. Такое решение адекватное?

Comment: Всё зависит от условий ваших. Так-то адекватное, да и почему нет? Вот [был ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469539/222168) про WCF и Discovery.

Comment: Просто если у вас 1 служба (один сервер), то смысл его искать каждый раз при обрыве коннекта? 1 раз нашли, запомнили, потом при обрыве подключаемся. Другое дело, если у вас условно 10 разных экземпляров одной службы и нет разницы от какой из них получать данные - отвалилась одна - идем ко второй, отвалилась вторая, ищем третью и т.д.

Comment: Там каждой службы, разные данные. Изображения рабочих столов

Comment: Воот, с этого и нужно было начинать ) Теперь более понятно, но все еще не совсем - у вас что-то типа удаленного наблюдения за десктопами? Экземпляры службы (серверы) по запросу клиента отдают скриншоты экрана, или же как-то иначе? Просто реализовать задачу можно несколькими путями.

Comment: Да они отдают скриншоты своего экрана. Ну, а также если с клиента поступает серверу определенный запрос, то сервер начинает принимать с клиента его рабочий стол. Например, для трансляции одного рабочего стола 15 машинам

Comment: Хотел уточнить - они отдают скриншоты по запросу с клиента? Или с заданной периодичностью каким-то образом шлют эти скрины "в никуда" и эти данные может принять кто хочет?

Comment: Они отдают по запросу с клиента. Запрос посылается каждые 500мс с помощью System.Timers

Comment: Верно понимаю, что у нас имеется служба, которая растиражирована на нескольких хост-машинах и по асинхронному запросу с подключенного клиента отдает некие данные (скрин рабочего стола). Проблема в том, что порой связь теряется (сервер завершил работу, например), а на клиенте из-за этого возникают ошибки и требуется переподключение помимо корректной обработки ошибок? Если так, то попробую дать ответ в общем виде.

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из беседы в комментариях и **не претендуя на роль абсолютной истины** мне видится, что в случае, когда имеется служба, растиражированная по нескольким хост-машинам (серверы службы), которые отдают некие данные по запросу с подключенного клиента, можно было бы организовать работу приблизительно так:

1. Создаем некий пул для сохранения списка серверов, который мог бы быть обновляем из разных потоков, например, через [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x13ttww7.aspx) `List<T>`, где `T` - либо класс, описывающий сервер, либо просто `string`, в котором хранится адрес для подключения службы на конкретной машине. Вместо `List` можно использовать какой-нибудь `Dictionary` или `Hashtable`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)), т.к. `Hashtable` исключает запись одинаковых значений в коллекцию, а мы же не хотим, что бы одна и та же машина, т.е. служба, фигурировала в списке дважды?.
   В любом случае, список доступных серверов может быть реализован через [неблокирующую синхронизацию](https://habrahabr.ru/post/130318/) (я бы так и сделал), либо напротив, на время работы со списком - он должен блокироваться для всех потоков, кроме того, что работает с ним в данный момент.
   Задача пула - хранить адреса ***актуальных*** серверов.
2. Далее, в самой WCF-службе делаем очень простой (и быстрый) метод, например, `bool Ping()`, который реально будет возвращать лишь `true`, и позволит нам проверить отклик от службы (сервера).
3. В отдельном потоке, или как `Task` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)) имеем полное право реализовать "наблюдатель" за серверами, который будет поддерживать наш пул в актуальном состоянии, т.е. удалять из него "отвалившиеся" серверы и добавлять новые. Сделать можно, например, используя [WCF service discovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456783%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([еще на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
4. Опять же отдельным потоком или таском реализуем функционал, который бы запрашивал, например, по таймеру, данные с сервиса (сервера), предварительно вызывая тот самый метод `Ping()`. Если служба не пингуется (нам не приходит ответ `true` какое-то время, то и не тратим на запрос данных с этой службы ресурсы, а из списка актуальных сервисов ее удалит наш наблюдатель из предыдущего пункта.
5. Так как коннект может быть потерян и во время передачи данных, то создаем обработчик ошибок, который скажет нам, что соединение прервалось, и всё. Потому что опять же, "отвалившийся" сервер будет удален из пула "наблюдателем", а, если появится вновь, то будет туда добавлен им же.

В принципе, тут есть масса путей для оптимизации и модификации: например, можно сделать так, что бы список хостов службы был доступен клиенту в виде файла (если число серверов конечное), тогда отпадает необходимость в Discovery - согласно такому списку достаточно хранить лишь некий флаг - он-лайн ли хост по такому-то адресу или нет, и в зависимости от этого решать - просить с него данные или нет.

Можно в принципе организовать работу иначе - например, на клиентской машине автоматически инстанцировать новый экземпляр клиента для каждого инстанса службы, тогда у каждой службы будет персональный клиент (но лучше так не делать, ибо ресурсы будет кушать и дополнительно все равно придется распределять, какой клиент с какой службой работает, да еще и ошибки обрабатывать).

Либо можно обойтись без "наблюдателя" - и актуализировать пул как раз из методов (метода), которые запрашивают данные и запускаются асинхронно в разных потоках - тут как раз пригодится `volatile`-коллекция.

В общем варианты могут быть еще более разнообразными, особенно если вспомнить, что на стороне службы тоже можно что-то делать при подключении и отключении клиента.

*Описанный выше способ просто показался мне наиболее простым и быстрым для реализации "в лоб". И еще раз повторюсь, что не претендую на абсолютную истину ни в коем разе.*